# Build 2 level javascript array inside loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, each

I dont know if the title is wrong... i dont know which term i should use to exaplain the desired result - the end result i am trying to achieve is this:

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
]
```

I am trying to build this type of array inside a .each loop while getting the values from a form (that can grow in the amount of rows..)

Here is what i got now (which "doesnt work"):

```
// GET VALUES FROM TR
var cnt = 0;
var datasets = [];
$('.pie-table > tbody > tr').length;
$('.pie-table > tbody > tr').each(function() {

    var ctrid = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    var size = $(ctrid).find('input#value').val();
    var color = $(ctrid).find('input#color').val();
    var hlight = $(ctrid).find('input#highlight').val();
    var label = $(ctrid).find('input#label').val();



    if (size.length > 0) {
        datasets[cnt] = 'value: ' + size + ', color:"' + color + '", highlight: "' + hlight + '", label: "' + label + '"';
    }

    cnt++;
})

var pieData = [];
for (var key in datasets) {
    pieData.push(datasets[key]);
};
```

How can i achive a structure similer to the example inside that loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object needs to be an object, not a string:

```
if (size.length > 0) {
  datasets[cnt] = {
    value: size,
    color: color,
    highlight: hlight,
    label: label
  };
}
```

Comment: This seems right! had to wrap "size" with parseInt - but other than that this works beautifuly! thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this:

```
if (size.length > 0) {
    // Take Blank Object
    var obj = {};

    // Create keys and assign value
    obj['value'] = size;
    obj['color'] = color;
    obj['highlight'] = hlight;
    obj['label'] = label;

    // Everything complete now push data in array
    datasets.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Wow, you are fast! i dont know why since chrome doesnt highlight the right line - just highlights some </div> instead but i get a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"